# Guess a number game , How to add or display number of guesses left using while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, codeblocks

Number guessing game which a user guess a number from 0-20 and i want it to display how many tries are left for the user for example the maximum tries is 5 and if the user got it wrong on the first try it will display something like "**tries left : 4**", how do i implement that in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    int randomNumber = rand() % 21;
    int num;
    int guess = 0;

    printf("\nThis is a guessing game.");
    printf("\nGuess 5 times only\n");

    printf("\nEnter your guess:");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    while (num != randomNumber && guess < 5){ //checks if num is equal or not to randomnumber and count is less than 5 or limit 5

        if(num > randomNumber){ // checks if num is greater than randomNumber
            printf("Too high! try again:");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            guess++;
        }

        if(num < randomNumber){ //checks if num is less than randomNumber
            printf("Too low! try again:");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            guess++;
        }

        if(num == randomNumber){ //checks if num is equal to randomNumber
            printf("You got it right!\n");
            return 0;
        }

        if(guess == 5) //checks if tries is 5 then exits program.
        {
            printf("your out guess of guesses!\n");
            return 0;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this inside your while loop (at the end)

```c
// For total no of guesses = 5, if that is n then n - 1 - guess  
printf("tries left %d\n", 4 - guess);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to print a value in a loop something along the lines of `printf(“You have %d guesses left\n”,5-guess);` might work

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer, but I would advise you using symbolic constants `#define GUESS_NUM 4` instead of actual numbers in your statements and your program in general, in programs like this it makes no difference, but you can get confused very easily in larger projects.

Also, your loop should end when guess reaches 4 because you already have one guess before the loop. You could write something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GUESS_NUM 4

int main()
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    int randomNumber = rand() % 21;
    int num;
    int guess = 0;

    printf("\nThis is a guessing game.");
    printf("\nGuess 5 times only\n");

    printf("\nEnter your guess:");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    while (num != randomNumber && guess < GUESS_NUM){ //checks if num is equal or not to randomnumber and count is less than 5 or limit 5
        
        if(num > randomNumber){ // checks if num is greater than randomNumber
            printf("tries left : %d\n", GUESS_NUM-guess);
            printf("Too high! try again:");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            guess++;
        }

        if(num < randomNumber){ //checks if num is less than randomNumber
            printf("tries left : %d\n", GUESS_NUM-guess);
            printf("Too low! try again:");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            guess++;
        }

        if(num == randomNumber){ //checks if num is equal to randomNumber
            printf("You got it right!\n");
            return 0;
        }

        if(guess == GUESS_NUM) //checks if tries is 5 then exits program.
        {
            printf("your out guess of guesses!\n");
            return 0;
        } 
        
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my bad you are right i did not notice i was exceeding at 6 much appreciated. also thanks for the heads up about the use of define,